# During C macro expansion, is there a special case for macros that would expand to "/*"?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c99

Here's a relevant example. It's obviously not valid **C**, but I'm just dealing with the preprocessor here, so the code doesn't actually have to compile.

```
#define IDENTITY(x) x
#define PREPEND_ASTERISK(x) *x
#define PREPEND_SLASH(x) /x

IDENTITY(literal)
PREPEND_ASTERISK(literal)
PREPEND_SLASH(literal)
IDENTITY(*pointer)
PREPEND_ASTERISK(*pointer)
PREPEND_SLASH(*pointer)
```

Running gcc's preprocessor on it:

```
gcc -std=c99 -E macrotest.c
```

This yields:

```
(...)

literal
*literal
/literal
*pointer
**pointer
/ *pointer
```

Please note the extra space in the last line.

This looks like a feature to prevent macros from expanding to "/*" to me, which I'm sure is well-intentioned. But at a glance, I couldn't find anything pertaining to this behaviour in the C99 standard. Then again, I'm inexperienced at **C**. Can someone shed some light on this? Where is this specified? I would guess that a compiler adhering to C99 should not just insert extra spaces during macro expansion just because it would probably prevent programming mistakes.

Answer (score 15):

The source code is already tokenized before being processed by CPP.

So what you have is a `/` and a `*` token that will not be combined implicitly to a `/*` "token" ( since /* is not really a preprocessor token I put it in "").

If you use -E to output preprocessed source CPP needs to insert a space in order to avoid `/*` being read by a subsequent compiler pass.

The same feature prevents from two e.g. `+` signs from different macros being combined into a `++` token on output.

The only way to really paste two preprocessor tokens together is with the ## operator:

```
#define P(x,y) x##y

...

P(foo,bar)
```

results in the token `foobar`

```
P(+,+)
```

results in the token `++`, but

```
P(/,*)
```

is not valid since `/*` is not a valid preprocessor token.

Comment: +1. I think the key insight is that the output of -E indeed isn't specified by the standard. The standard talks about the program consisting of a sequence of preprocessing tokens, and then later it's converted to a sequence of tokens. It's entirely up to the preprocessor how to represent those sequences, and in this case how to serialize them to a file as a sequence of *bytes*. Of course the only viable serialization is one which will be read back as an equivalent series of preprocessing tokens, so as you say, it must put whitespace between two tokens that together would form one.

Comment: I agree 100%, wanted to write something like your explanation but hadn't enoght time.

Comment: Good answer, though I have two nitpicky comments:  There's no such thing as a `/*` token; comments are removed from the source before it is tokenized.  You could form a `++` token from two `+` tokens using `##`.

Comment: Yes me mentioning a /* "token" was a simplification and easier to explain.  And sure you can join two parts into a token with ## but I was talking about "implicit" joining and not explicit gluing with ##

Comment: BTW you cant paste / and * together with ## should you want to try it, since the result of a ## operation must be a valid preprocessor token.  And as you correctly mentioned /* is not a preprocessor token.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of the pre-processor is standardized. In the summary at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor , the results you are observing are the effect of:

"3: Tokenization - The preprocessor breaks the result into preprocessing tokens and whitespace. It replaces comments with whitespace".

This takes place before:

"4: Macro Expansion and Directive Handling".